# CSS Percentages of other elements

Tags: css, layout

Is it possible to specify a CSS dimension as a percentage *of another element other than its parent*? For example, I would like to specify the border-radius of a div to be 10% of the width of the div.  However, `border-radius: 10%` makes the border elliptical when the div's height is unequal to its width.  Can I somehow specify all border radii to be equal to 5% of the width of the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with pure CSS, but easily possible with Javascript/jQuery.

`$('#firstelement').css('border-radius',$('#secondelement').width()/10+'px');`

would be an example.

Answer (score -1):

You could specify a fixed size in pixels.